# When using the re module in python, the result obtained using the \S$ match will be missing the last element in the string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
pattern_s = '^((?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?\d).{6,})\S$'
c = 'ABab12'
b = re.findall(pattern_s, c)
print(b)   # []

d = 'ABCabc123'
e = re.findall(pattern_s, d)
print(e)   # ['ABCabc12']
```

but

```
pattern_t = '^((?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?\d).{6,})$'
c = 'ABab12'
b = re.findall(pattern_t, c)
print(b)   # ['ABab12']
```

Why does this happen? Is there a problem with my writing method or other factors?

Answer (score 0):

The `\S` at the end of your regex must always match one non-space character -- the last character in your string, since it is followed by `$`. So when possible, your capturing group will match something that does not include this last character.

I strongly advise avoiding lookahead patterns (`(?=...)` and variants) in all circumstances. Using three in the same regex is most certainly unnecessary. If you could explain what you are trying to do, we can all give you suggestions for how to do it better.

Comment: I want to write a regular expression to verify that the characters entered are legal (there must be a [A-Z] and [a-z] and [0-9], but no spaces).

Comment: Your code would be much cleaner if you do not try to make a single regex do all that. E.g. you can check if there is a digit with `any(c.isdigit() for c in mystring)`.